# Looking for Nativscript/Angular 2 SideDrawer equivalent

Tags: angular, nativescript

I would like to integrate the RadSideDrawer or equivalent to my Nativescript/Angular 2 app, but not sure how to.

I know there is explanation here: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/SideDrawer/getting-started

I tried to apply it directly and nothing happened

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are separate instructions for the Angular versions of each of the UI for NativeScript controls. Here are the instructions for the RadSideDrawer: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/SideDrawer/getting-started. Note that the latest release of UI for NativeScript does not support Angular 2’s last RC 1 release, although an update to support that is coming soon.

Comment: Hi @tj-vantoll, thanks for the answer. They don't mention to download anything special like you did here: http://developer.telerik.com/featured/building-polished-mobile-apps-telerik-ui-nativescript/. It is true?

Comment: Just noticed that no sidedrawer available in the free version. That's correct?

Comment: Hey David, the sidedrawer is in the free version. And the article at http://developer.telerik.com/featured/building-polished-mobile-apps-telerik-ui-nativescript/ doesn’t mention the Angular controls because at the time Angular wasn’t supported in UI for NativeScript.

Comment: @TJVanToll : I've a problem accessing sideDrawer and toggleDrawerState . I've followed  http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/SideDrawer/getting-started to create template and used the code mentioned in https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/blob/release/sdkAngular/app/sidedrawer/getting-started/getting-started.component.ts with a few changes

I've logged the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756079/nativescript-toggledrawerstate-not-a-function-error.