# NativeScript: toggleDrawerState not a function error

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I'm trying to create a sample application in native script. I used RadSideDrawer for sidemenu in the following way by referencing http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/SideDrawer/getting-started :

```
<RadSideDrawer [transition]="RevealTransition" #drawer>
  <StackLayout tkDrawerContent class="sideStackLayout">
      <StackLayout class="sideTitleStackLayout">
          <Label text="Navigation Menu"></Label>
      </StackLayout>
      <StackLayout class="sideStackLayout">
          <Label text="Primary" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
          <Label text="Social" class="sideLabel"></Label>
          <Label text="Promotions" class="sideLabel"></Label>
          <Label text="Labels" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
          <Label text="Important" class="sideLabel"></Label>
          <Label text="Starred" class="sideLabel"></Label>
          <Label text="Sent Mail" class="sideLabel"></Label>
          <Label text="Drafts" class="sideLabel"></Label>
      </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>
  <StackLayout tkMainContent>
    <GridLayout rows="*">
    <page-router-outlet ></page-router-outlet>
    <ActivityIndicator #activityIndicator horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center"  width="100" height="100" row="0"></ActivityIndicator>
  </GridLayout>
  </StackLayout>
</RadSideDrawer>
```

In my app.component.ts, I've given :

```
import {RadSideDrawer} from "nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer";

@ViewChild("drawer") drawer : ElementRef;
```

and

```
public toggleDrawer(){
        let drawer = <RadSideDrawer>this.drawer.nativeElement;
        drawer.toggleDrawerState();
    }
```

The problem is that whenever I'm trying to execute toggleDrawer(), I'm getting an error :

```
 drawer.toggleDrawerState not a function.
```

What could be gone wrong? I'm getting a this.drawer as an [object Object] and this.drawer.nativeElement as ProxyViewContainer(5), that means it is identifying the element, but cannot call toggleDrawerState();

Also the style is distorted now, it is now listing the tkDrawerContent in the main view and I'm not able to see the original page contents I specified in tkMainContent.

Comment: sorry but where do you get the `.nativeElement` because I don't see it anywhere in API Reference

Comment: Checkout chapter 4 in nativescript tutorial https://docs.nativescript.org/tutorial/ng-chapter-4. I am getting other elements using this method, only RadSideDrawer has the problem.

Comment: It is a property in ElementRef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some things to consider with RadSideDrawer (in N+Angular2 project).

1.) You have a special import  for typings

```
import { RadSideDrawerComponent, SideDrawerType } from "nativescript-telerik-ui-pro/sidedrawer/angular";

@ViewChild(RadSideDrawerComponent) public drawerComponent: RadSideDrawerComponent;
private drawer: SideDrawerType;
```

2.) You need to implement ChangeDetectorRef in the constructor of your component

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, Injectable, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";
.....
constructor(private page: Page, private _changeDetectionRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
        super();
}
```

3.) In ngAfterViewInit use the ChangeDetectorRef like this

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.drawer = this.drawerComponent.sideDrawer;
    this._changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
}
```

4.) Finally uses the drawer method is trivial

```
public toggleDrawer() {
    this.drawer.toggleDrawerState();
}

.....
<Button text="TOGGLE DRAWER" (tap)=toggleDrawer()></Button>
```

The full example for using RadSideDrawer with angular can be found [here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/blob/release/sdkAngular/app/sidedrawer/getting-started/getting-started.component.ts)

Comment: In the 3rd step, I'm getting an error this.drawerComponent is undefined.

Comment: I'm getting an [object Object]  if I use   @ViewChild("drawer") drawerComponent: RadSideDrawerComponent;

but this.drawerComponent.sideDrawer is getting as undefined.

Comment: Don't get your drawer by id : See the working demo from here https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/blob/release/sdkAngular/app/sidedrawer/getting-started/getting-started.component.ts

Comment: if I use that method , I'm getting undefined value for this.drawerComponent in the 3rd step you mentioned here.

Comment: I'm using the free version of telerik-ui

Comment: Found out the mistake, I was not injecting SIDEDRAWER_DIRECTIVES in my app.module.ts. Thanks for the help!